# How to know tab switch in standard WPF Tab Control

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, tabcontrol

The issue is like

I have tab control

I just want to set a flag when user switches between existing open tabs.
I want to perform a operation only when tab is switched.

And I don't want perform that operation when user adds a new tab or opens existing tab. 
(i.e If there are 2 tabs open - when I add a tab - total tabs open is now 3, or I open a existing tab - count is again 3) In this case I don't want to perform that operation.

I do use OnSelectionChanged()
but this is raised all the times, i.e when I switch the tab or add tab.

I want a event that just tells me that a tab is switched.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no event that tells you that the user switched between existing tabs. You can hold the current tabs in a list (or dictionary) and when the SelectionChanged event is fired, you can check if the current tab exists in the list (or dictionary) this way you can know if the user switched between old tabs or added or created a new tab.
After that you can add the new tab to the list (or dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand what you are trying to do, but you could probably use the TabIndex property.  Bind it to your viewmodel and have a list or something track which indexes get selected to determine if a tab has been selected previously.